# Batch-file command (net user and findstr) with output convert to javascript

Tags: javascript, batch-file, vbscript, hta

I write a HTA File with javascript to display some userinformation.
How can I run windows cmd commands (like in a batch file) and get the output in a variable.

What I need in Javascript syntax

batch-file code
    net user %username% /domain | findstr /c:"password expires"

so that I have this in a variable in javascript function.

Same like this:

```
function username()
        {
        var wshshell=new ActiveXObject("wscript.shell");
        var username=wshshell.ExpandEnvironmentStrings("%username%");
        return username
        }



function ipAddress() {
            var ipAddress = "";
            var wmi = GetObject("winmgmts:{impersonationLevel=impersonate}");
            e = new Enumerator(wmi.ExecQuery("SELECT * FROM Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration WHERE IPEnabled = True"));
                for(; !e.atEnd(); e.moveNext()) {
                    var s = e.item(); 
                    ipAddress = s.IPAddress(0);
                }
            return ipAddress        
        }
```

Comment: Is there a reason why you cannot read/retrieve the information directly in `js`? Even if you cannot find a more direct way of attaining the data, `net.exe` is an executable file, _so you should still be able to run it and capture its output without the added baggage of a batch file!_

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use WScript.shell object. It allows you to execute shell commands.

```
var objShell = new ActiveXObject("WScript.shell");
```

It has run method. 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/desktop/legacy/bb776890(v=vs.85)

Comment: Thank you :). I write a batch file and start it with shell.run command to geht the output in a txt file and to read in my hta in javascript and vbs script section.